# Running a batch file with subprocess

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, subprocess

I'd like to execute a simple batch file using Python. But I'm getting some error back from the process saying the file, directory or disc name is not right. I guess the best way to start is to show the code:

```
import subprocess as sp
from pathlib import Path

file = Path(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\test.bat')

p = sp.Popen(['"' + str(file) + '"'], stdin=sp.PIPE, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE,
             shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
outs, errs = p.communicate('', timeout=5)
print(outs, '\n-----\n', errs)
```

I extended this with appending to system path and changing the working directory:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append(file.parent)
os.chdir(file.parent)
```

The batch file contains just a few echo commands for debugging. So I'd expect the code above to print the contents of the echoes. I've verified that I'm able to call it inside a command prompt from any folder. Previously I was getting some file permission error (`WinError 5`), so that might be related especially as the file is in Program Files. This error was not from the process, but Python itself.

I also tried it with an executable, and a similar error was raised: `WinError 2: the system cannot find the file specified`. Any idea where I'm stumbling?

---

#### Attempts

- When the `shell=True` keyword is removed, the `WinError 5` is back
- When `Popen` is called with `['cmd']` and the batch file is run with `p.communicate('"' + str(file) + '"\n', timeout=5)`, no errors are thrown, and the output contains the echoes. However batch files should run without explicitly opening a command prompt, I presume.

Comment: Just a suggestion . Maybe try os.path.normpath("path/foreslash/rather/than/backslash".

Comment: @NihalSangeeth The sole purpose of `pathlib.Path` here is to avoid that very confusion. Should you print `file`, it has forward slashes. I only used backslashes because Windows uses them. And on Windows, `normpath` [converts](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath) forward slashes to backward ones. This makes `str(file)` and `os.path.normpath(file)` equivalent. (`str` around a path converts the slashes of a Windows path)

Comment: can you verify you can open this file like open(file,"r") ?

Comment: @NihalSangeeth I indeed can open it: `with open(file, 'r') as f:
    print(f.read())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a command-line string instead of an args list when passing `shell=True` or when running a batch script with the default `shell=False`.

On Windows, `Popen` processes an args list into a command line that's compatible with VC++ argument parsing. But cmd.exe don't use VC++ argument parsing rules, and even for an executable that does use VC++ rules (e.g. python.exe), the extra quotes you're adding (i.e. `'"' + str(file) + '"'`) get backslash-escaped as literal quotation marks in the command line.